# Building Unix Top from source

Tags: compilation, freebsd

I'm trying to build top(1) from sources under FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE (clang version 3.4.1).

```
# fetch http://www.unixtop.org/dist/top-3.7.tar.gz
# tar -xzf top-3.7.tar.gz
# cd top-3.7
# ./configure
# make
# make install
```

Compilation goes without errors, but the binary compiled don't work, giving me error as below:

```
# top
kvm_open: kvm_nlist: No such file or directory
kvm_open: kvm_nlist: No such file or directory
kvm_open: kvm_nlist: No such file or directory
kvm_open: kvm_nlist: No such file or directory
kvm_open: kvm_nlist: No such file or directory
kvm_open: kvm_nlist: No such file or directory
kvm_open: kvm_nlist: No such file or directory
kernel: no symbol named `_cp_time'
```

What is my mistake, how to make it work? I have tried with version 3.6 and 3.7, with clang and gcc, under 10.1-RELEASE and 8.4-RELEASE with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's a sign of FreeBSD support in upstream top being rather obsolete.  Which is kind of obvious, since FreeBSD is using its own fork.

Perhaps it would be easier to port the specific features you need from upstream to FreeBSD version, instead of the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version you used is not compatible with the version of FreeBSD you run.

The sourcecode for top(1) is found in /usr/src/contrib/top
The Makefile glue is in /usr/src/usr.bin/top

Comment: Yes, I know about `/usr/src/`, but it contains old version of Unix top - I'm trying to get newer one. Building from `/usr/src/usr.bin/top` works fine.

Comment: Well if you are missing something from the standard top, look at the differences between the different versions. Also you might look at what changes where made when the current version of top was imported into the FreeBSD source tree